# Using group_by with difftime

Tags: r

I've created a dataframe with data :

```
idCol <- c('1','1','2','2')
stepCol <- c('step1' , 'step2' , 'step1' , 'step2')
timestampCol <- c('01-01-2017:09.00', '01-01-2017:10.00', '01-01-2017:09:00', '01-01-2017:14.00')
mydata <- data.frame(idCol , stepCol , timestampCol)
colnames(mydata) <- c('id' , 'steps' , 'timestamp')
```

stepCol is the start time for a given id, when step2 begins this means step1 has ended.
I'm attempting to generate a tibble that contains the average of the duration for each id based on step start time.

So I'm attempting to generate :

```
step , averagetime
step1 , 1 hour
step2 , 5 hours
```

Closest I've got is :

```
diffTime <- c(0, difftime(ymd_hms(mydata$timestamp[-1]), ymd_hms(mydata$timestamp[-nrow(mydata)]), units="hours"))
diffTime %>% group_by(id, steps) %>% summarize(mean(diffTime))
```

But returns error :

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some minor editing to your code but basically you need to associate the results of `ymd_hms` with your `mydata`:

```
mydata$diffTime <- c(0, difftime(lubridate::ymd_hms(mydata$timestamp[-1]), 
                          lubridate::ymd_hms(mydata$timestamp[-nrow(mydata)]), units="hours"))
diffTime <- mydata %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(mean(diffTime))
```

Returns:

```
R> diffTime
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     id `mean(diffTime)`
  <chr>            <dbl>
1     1         0.008333
2     2         0.033333
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note there is inconsistencies in the sample data `timestamp` column for the time nomenclature

```
timestampCol <- c('01-01-2017:09.00', '01-01-2017:10.00', '01-01-2017:09.00', '01-01-2017:14.00')
```

Converting strings to time values (accounting for factors)

```
mydata$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(strptime(levels(mydata$timestamp)[mydata$timestamp], format="%m-%d-%Y:%H.%M"))

library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(diff = difftime(timestamp, lag(timestamp))) %>%
  summarise(na.omit(diff))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
      id `na.omit(diff)`
  <fctr>          <time>
1      1         1 hours
2      2         5 hours
```